# Constraint optimization problem

Tags: economics, constraints

Suppose pigs $\left(Q\right)$ can be fed corn-based feed $\left(C\right)$ or soybean-based feed $\left(S\right)$ such that the production function is $Q = 2C + 5S$. If the price of corn is feed is $\$4$ and the price of soybean feed is $\$5$, what is the cost minimizing combination of producing $p=200$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: honestly i dont know where to start, because it has  no powers I dont know how to use the derivatives to determine a minimum cost

Comment: Also what is $p$?

Comment: I dont know, it wasnt specified to me, im presuming it is the output 200 = 2c + 5s

Comment: Whoever wrote the question wasn't very good at specifying variables: this only makes sense if $p$ references the pigs, which are also referred to as $Q$.

Comment: I know, lecturer isnt very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to look at the marginal utilities of each of your inputs, i.e. the corn and the soybean feed. From the production function, we see that per unit of corn, we get $2$, and per unit of soybean, we get $5$. Thus, the ratio of marginal utilities of corn to soybean is $\frac{2}{5}$. Then, we can look at the price ratio of corn to soybean, which is $\frac{4}{5}$. What does this tell us about which feed we're going to prefer? How much of that feed are we going to use? (Hint: look at the difference in price ratio and marginal utility.)

An alternative method: for every four dollars I invest in corn, I get two units of "pig" in return. For every five dollars I invest in soybean, I get five units of "pig" in return. Which of these two has a better cost/return ratio? Would I use the other input if these ratios are not equal?

Comment: I get where you're going, optimimum is where the ratio of marginal utilities is equal to the slope of the prices right? but even from there how tcould you deduce the actual quantities

Comment: I'm more hinting at the fact that non-extreme solutions will occur when those ratios are equal. When they are not equal, there is no reason to prefer one input to the other one: if I get $10$ times the production out of one input at half of the price, why would I consider using the other?

Comment: truth be told i dont know how to go about this,  what would you say the optimimum budle is ? could you show workings

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, does it make more sense?

Comment: yes, by that logic you would only use soy , and given that you have to produce 200, you would use 40 soy and zero corn ?

Comment: Correct, that's what I was getting at. :)

Comment: thanks buddy, appreciate it